# How to add Search with Meteor and Bootstrap?

Tags: meteor

I am trying to implement searching in my Meteor app. I don't exactly understand how it ties together.  At this point, I have this following code:

html:

```
<form class="navbar-search pull-left">
  <input type="text" class="search-query" placeholder="Search">
</form>
```

js:

```
Template.menubar.events({
  'keyup input.search-query': function (evt) {
    console.log("Keyup value: " + evt.which);
    if (evt.which === 13) {
      console.log("Got an Enter keyup");
      Session.set("searchQuery", "justATestVar");
    }
  }
});
```

I can see the values of keyup as I press different keys into the search box, so I know the event is being hit.  Capturing the "enter" keyup also works, but pressing enter causes the enter site to reload and when I do:

```
Session.get("searchQuery")
```

it returns undefined.

I don't know if I'm handling this properly.  Essentially, I just want to get the value from the search box and then use that value for making a search on my collection.  Any help would be appreciated!  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is probably happening is your form is being submitted when you hit enter. Try an `preventDefault()`. Probably something like this would work:

```
Template.menubar.events({ 
  'keyup input.search-query': function (evt) {
     console.log("Keyup value: " + evt.which);
     if (evt.which === 13) {
       console.log("Got an Enter keyup");
       Session.set("searchQuery", "justATestVar");
     }
   },
   'submit form': function (evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();
   }
 ...
```

You could also try adding `evt.preventDefault();` in your keyup but I think it's the form submission that's doing it.

Answer (score 7):

You should really use a submit button for your search form to avoid ruining accessibility.
Using a submit button will also enable by default the behavior you're looking for : form submission on enter key pressed.
If you really want to get rid of the submit button, keep it in the DOM but use CSS to hide it.

It's very important to call preventDefault on the event you'll receive from "submit form" handler, if you forget to do so, the page will refresh ruining the meteor "Single Page App" experience (and by the way, page refresh will clear your Session variables, which is why you get an undefined value in the first place).

```
"submit form":function(event,template){
    event.preventDefault();
    Session.set("searchQuery",template.find(".search-query").value);
}
```

Comment: The earlier answer actually answered my question earlier, but youre absolutely right.  Thank you, I will add in the search button!

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone got here trying to implement the search function as well, I recommend the following:

```
meteor add matteodem:easy-search
```

On client and server:

```
Players = new Meteor.Collection('players');
// name is the field of the documents to search over
Players.initEasySearch('name');
```

On the client, make a `template.html`:

```
<template name="searchBox">
    {{> esInput index="players" placeholder="Search..." }}
    <ul>
        {{#esEach index="players"}}
            <li>Name of the player: {{name}}</li>
        {{/esEach}}
    </ul>
</template>
```

[Reference](https://github.com/matteodem/meteor-easy-search)